# DokuWiki on Cloud Foundry "Your PHP seems to miss SSL support"

Tags: php, ssl, web-deployment, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I deployed successfully DokuWiki with PHP Buildpack `v4.3.14`. Because storage is not persistent, this is kind of useless testing (I am waiting for [Cloud Foundry Volume Services](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/volman))

> [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/dokuwiki#) is a simple to use and highly versatile Open Source wiki
>   software that doesn't require a database.

```
$ cat .bp-config/options.json 
{
        "WEBDIR": ""
}
```

I receive this error

```
Your PHP seems to miss SSL support. Downloading will not work for many DokuWiki extensions.
```

[image]

Howto enable PHP SSL support in PHP buildpack? How do I see all possible options (list) from PHP buildpack? All possible value for `.bp-config/options.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the possible values for the PHP_MODULES variable are the ones listed in the manifest of the Buildpack. Eg. the openssl module here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack/blob/master/manifest.yml#L84